# Best practice to insert multiple requests, getting via API and store in Database without missing

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've webhook, which is hitting with multiple entries on my function. Sometime when there are 10 to 15 request, the database insert and update query is missing.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

There could be many solutions like :-

- Add Queuing system, on api request add job in queue response back & let queue add to database.
- Use what databases do, they add to file and then from file they push to database.

There could be many other solutions and also maybe above 2 may not work for you perfectly, which solution to choose depends upon what you are doing

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, I'am using Queuing system RabbitMq but I'am afraid maybe it'll missing to add in queue too, whats your thought

Comment: So, keep check on errors and log errors in place where you can see, and on errors add data in a file, so when you have checked the error (whatever it was, and it is fixed) then feed data from file to database .

Comment: Thanks for your time